# Regex pattern needs to match only the first occurrence and not be "greedy"

Tags: c#, regex

I'm stumped on one pattern that keeps returning all matches beyond the first (it's "greedy")
my pattern: ISS/(?\w\S*)
Where the text has two matches:

ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09

I only want the C# regex to return the first match "2018-03-02"

```
    private static readonly Regex tagIssueDateRegex = new Regex(
        @"ISS\/(?<issue>\w+\S*)",
        RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ucMhBJ

Comment: Make sure you are using `Match` instead of `Matches` in your c# code.

Comment: What is the string that you want to match?  `\w+\S*` is a very broad match for `2005-03-09`

Comment: For simplicity sake - just two lines for here will do if I can just get back as a match only for the first ( and each one is one a new line which I cannot seem to reproduce in the edit box) 

ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Non-Greedy

For non-greedy, we would just add a `s` flag:

```
ISS\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

#### [DEMO for non-greedy](https://regex101.com/r/MChlxb/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"ISS\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})";
        string input = @"ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09
ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09
ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Singleline;

        Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, options);
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
}
```

#### Greedy

I'm guessing that we wish to only return the first instance of ISS followed by a date, for which, we would start with an expression:

```
ISS\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})
```

then we would add one of these expressions:

```
[\s\S]*
[\w\W]*
[\d\D]*
[\s\S].*
[\w\W].*
[\d\D].*
```

to swipe all chars and new lines to the end of our string, and we would have:

```
ISS\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[\s\S]*
```

if I understand the question correctly.

We can add or reduce our boundaries, if necessary.

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"ISS\/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})[\s\S]*";
        string input = @"ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09
ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09
ISS/2018-03-02 
ISS/2005-03-09";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### [DEMO for greedy](https://regex101.com/r/3rIOM1/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps explain how `\s\S` differs from `.`?

Comment: Awesome and thorough answer - thanks so much! I wound up simply modifying my original pattern thusly and it works now! ISS\/(?<issue>\w\S*)[\s\S]*

Answer (score 2):

Note that in your pattern `\w+\S*` is a very broad match for the date like part.

You can use your pattern and use [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_) to get the first occurrence.

```
string pattern = @"ISS\/(?<issue>\w\S*)";
string input = @"ISS/2018-03-02
ISS/2005-03-09";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
var res = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
Console.WriteLine(res.Value);
```

Result:

```
ISS/2018-03-02
```

[C# Demo](https://ideone.com/LocR6N)

If you want a more specific match for a date like format you could use:

```
\bISS/(?<issue>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})\b
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cbISS%2f%28%3f%3cissue%3e%5cd%7b4%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d-%5cd%7b2%7d%29%5cb&i=ISS%2f2018-03-02+%0d%0aISS%2f2005-03-09)

Comment: I should have added that in my code context I have to have this group. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
^ISS\/(?<issue>\w+\S*)
```

If there can be text before the first "ISS", use this one:

```
^.*?ISS\/(?<issue>\w+\S*)
```

`^` means "beginning of the line", `.*?` means "any character, from 0 to n times, as few as possible.

Comment: Both of these suggestion still return two times - two from Group 'issue'

Comment: @user1836609: I don't agree, try this:

`var rx = new Regex( @"^.*?ISS\/(?<issue>\w+\S*)" );

var matches = rx.Matches( "ISS/2018-03-02 ISS/2005-03-09" );
  
Console.WriteLine( matches.Count );`

You can also use `\n` as the separator between the two "ISS", same result.